# Is this on-topic or a discussion question?

Tags: discussion

https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/whats-the-meaning-of-these-lines-in-midsummer-nights-dream

Is he asking "Please translate Shakespeare into modern English" or "Please do my homework for me"? I feel like it's the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite clearly off-topic. I've closed the question and left a note for the poster.